# Express migration from 3 to 4 errors

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, reveal.js

I tried to migration from express 3 to 4 with my app.js as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var config = require('./config').config;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var router = express.Router();
var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');


var http = require('http');
var app = module.exports.app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')({
  //io.set('log level', 1); // reduce level of logging to warning only  
  transports  : [ 'websocket' 
    , 'flashsocket'
    , 'htmlfile'
    , 'xhr-polling'
    , 'jsonp-polling'  
  ],
}).listen(server);  //pass a http.Server instance
server.listen(80);  //listen on port 80

// configure express
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(methodOverride());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(session({ 
     secret: 'your secret here', 
     resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));
  app.use(router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
  app.use(errorhandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
}
else { app.use(errorhandler()); }

// remote control the presentation server code
routes.setupRemotePresenter(app, io, config);

var server1 = app.listen(80, function () {
    var host = server1.address().address
    var port = server1.address().port
    //console.log(("Express server listening on port %d ", port);
});
```

The errors are below

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

    Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::80
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
        at Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
        at listen (net.js:1267:10)
        at Server.listen (net.js:1363:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\remote-presentation-controller-master\app_bak.js:24:8)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

It could be something with socket.io which I ma not familiar with. How can i fix this?

The original app.js is here for reference

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , config = require('./config').config;

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// socket io
var io = require('socket.io');

// socket io setup
io = io.listen(app);

// configure socket.io
io.configure(function () {

  // recommended production testing
  //io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
  //io.enable('browser client etag');          // apply etag caching logic based on version number
  //io.enable('browser client gzip');          // gzip the file

  io.set('log level', 1); // reduce level of logging to warning only

  io.set('transports', [
      'websocket'
    , 'flashsocket'
    , 'htmlfile'
    , 'xhr-polling'
    , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);


});


// configure express
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your secret here' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});


// remote control the presentation server code
routes.setupRemotePresenter(app, io, config);

app.listen(80);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Looks to me like you already have something running on part 80.

Comment: That's right. Thanks Robert:)